# Why function not returning promise 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'?

Tags: angularjs

Is coming up this error  'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' i wonder why factory not returning object.

Controller:

```
 angular
    .module('sfcMachinesFieldDefinitions')
    .controller('MachinesListController', ['$translate', '$http', '$scope', '$state', 'ListOfMachines',
function ($translate, $http, $scope, $state, ListOfMachines) {
         var vm = this;
          vm.allMachines = function () {
             return ListOfMachines.allMachines().then(function (response) {

                 console.log('The respounse' + JSON.stringify(response))
                 vm.response = response;

             })
             return response;
           };
```

Service Factory:

```
 angular
    .module('sfcMachinesFieldDefinitions')
    .factory('ListOfMachines', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {

            allMachines: function () { 
                $http.post('MachineList/GetAllMachines/').then(function (response) { 

                    return response;
                   })}
          };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't return an object because you're not returning it.

It should be

```
...
allMachines: function () { 
    return $http.post('MachineList/GetAllMachines/')...
}
...
```